# How to use Project wide ssh keys with terraform

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, terraform

There is another post on here about how to add ssh keys to your terraform instance. But, my question is how do you use project wide ssh keys within terraform?

```
    /*CREATE INSTANCE TEMPLATE*/
resource "google_compute_instance_template" "template-030601" {
  name        = "terraform-template-030601"
  description = "This template is used to create app server instances."

  tags = ["foo", "bar"]

  labels = {
    environment = "sbx"
  }

  instance_description = "description assigned to instances"
  machine_type         = "f1-micro"
  can_ip_forward       = false


  //Create a new boot disk from an image
  disk {
        source_image = "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/hp-img-cof-st-core-prd/global/images/cof-ubuntu1604-180124"
        auto_delete  = false
        boot         = true
  }

  network_interface {
    subnetwork         = "${var.subnet}"
    subnetwork_project = "${var.subnet_project}"
  }

  metadata {
      sshKeys = 
  }

  metadata_startup_script = "${data.template_file.install_script.rendered}"

}
```

Comment: Does google cloud support the key pair as aws did (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-ec2-keypairs.html)?

Comment: yup it does. easy answer to this is dont set sshkeys metadata. Just make sure that you set the public key inside the project wide repository inside GCP. It will auto apply to the instances.

Answer (score 4):

First of all if you want to use metadata keys across the project need to create a separate section with your ssh-keys (is useful the heredoc syntax if you need to specify multiple keys):

```
resource "google_compute_project_metadata_item" "ssh_keys" {
  key   = "ssh-keys"
  value = <<EOF
    user1:ssh-rsa <YOUR_SSH_PUBLIC_KEY> user1@darkstar
    user2:ssh-rsa <YOUR_SSH_PUBLIC_KEY> user2@domain
  EOF
}
```

Then in your `google_compute_instance` you need to specify `block-project-ssh-keys` in your metadata configuration. So try to add this:

```
resource "google_compute_instance_template" "template-030601" {
  ...
  metadata {
    block-project-ssh-keys = false
  }
  ...
}
```

If you want enable it substitute `false` with `true`
Hope that is useful

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think it could be one of the 2 as I'm trying to figure out how to add ssh keys to my project
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_project_metadata_item.html
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_project_metadata.html
Hope this helps in some way